# When to add "been" to present perfect tense

Tags: present-perfect

- **I have** asked my parents to loan me some money.
- **He has** saved enough money to buy a car.
- **She has** read many books.

---

- **You have `been`** really helpful today.
- **They have `been`** married for three years.

These sentences are taken from an online tutorial for present perfect tense. My question is why some sentences are decorated with "been" word. What we expect by adding "been". What if I write those sentences without "been" word? Ex:

> You have really helpful today.
>
> They have married for three years.

or what if I add "been" to other sentences? Ex:

> I have been asked my parents to loan me some money.
>
> He has been saved enough money to buy a car.
>
> She has been read many books.

Is there any rule to use "been" word? I'm really confused about this. Can anyone clarify this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is a question of very, very basic English grammar which should be covered in any half-decent basic book or online resource on English grammar. As such, it is not on-topic on this site, which is for those things that _cannot_ be found in commonly-available resources. Try changing it to present tense: would you say “I am ask my parents” or “he is saves money”? Or “you helpful” or “they married for three years”? No. Nor would you in the perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been is the past participle of be. Asked, saved, and read are the past participles of ask, save, and read respectively.

> Formation of active voice present perfect: have/has + past participle of verb (e.g. been, saved, etc.)

Therefore, in active voice present perfect, "been" is not needed in the 1st to 3rd examples, and is needed in the 4th to 5th examples.

Hope this could be of help!